# How do I get the login information for REST API?

Tags: api, rest

Trying to begin development of an external app using the Force.com Toolkit for .NET https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET, but I cannot see where I'm supposed to get the various security data (consumerKey, consumerSecret etc.) or enable API access.

I have a developer login and a standard trial user login as well, but wandering round the Setup menu on the old interface I can't find a way to enable REST access and get the credentials.

I thought I'd find the answer here on StackExchange but I cannot see any relevant questions.

Comment: Did you set up a connected app? That is where you would get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Setup-> App -> Create a new Connected App

[image]

save this record. On the detail page of this record you would find the consumer secret key.